# react.js got that : timestamp is assigned a value but never used

Tags: reactjs

I am using react.js with eslint and I got that :

`'timestamp' is assigned a value but never used`

the line is this one :

```
const { latitude, longitude, timestamp, accuracy, error } = usePosition();
```

but I don't know how can I do to solve that problem ...

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Use it in your code, remove it, or ignore it (its just a linting rule, not breaking code).

Answer (score 0):

You have imported `timestamp` and haven't used it anywhere in the code.
If you don't need it, remove it from the code to avoid this warning.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have declared value for `timestamp` but not used it in a code. It is just a warning. To get rid of it, simply remove the variable .